# 720p or 1080p - How to verify the same?

Tags: video

All,
I recently bought a cell with 1920 x 1080 resolution. When i search for a 1080p video in Youtube ad play it, it plays fine. However, the same video is playable in another cell with only 720p screen resolution. How can that be possible? How can we verify if the video played in youtube is just HD or Full-HD?

Comment: You could use a [system info app](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_systeminfo) to show the device's specifications.

Comment: "*How can that be possible?*" -- why not? Scaling can be done by a software. Related: [What are the differences of watching a 1080p and a 720p version of the same media on a 720p screen?](http://superuser.com/q/819514) / [On a 720p monitor, should it be possible for me to see 1080p? Or at least the difference between the two?](http://superuser.com/q/857999) / [Does 2K or 4K media look better than HD on 1080p monitor?](http://superuser.com/q/906656)

Answer (score 1):

You tube videos while titled Full HD do not appear to be playing at that resolution.  When you click the three button vertical bar on top right, you get a menu option and the central one which is a gear icon displays resolution, which is lower.

For downloaded videos,  you can always check the resolution using VLC [player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc) properties listed under video track

Some cell phones like mine Honor 6 have an option to lower the screen  resolution  to achieve better performance and battery life. Hence, as suggested in comments, please do check the properties of resolution